# How to get 100% Coverage for this statement in java using junit

Tags: junit

I have the following code in java.

```
if( response != null && response.getResponseBlock() != null)
{
    //do something 
}
```

How can I cover 100% Branch coverage of the condition in the if ().

Even though the condition is a valid java statement, I can never achieve the case when getResponseBlock is not null but response is null.

Please advise.

Comment: Is it a state which is prevented by a Java Language Specification itself?
I liked the words of Uncle Bob here: http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2017/03/06/TestingLikeTheTSA.html

Treat 100% [coverage] as an asymptotic goal.

Comment: of course you cant ^^ why would you want to test something impossible ?

Comment: It feels good to achieve 100% line and branch coverage for every line of code that we write. So thinking on that line, I was just thinking how I can achieve 100% coverage. If I cannot, how should I refactor it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel the answer is as the comment : 
Is it a state which is prevented by a Java Language Specification itself? I liked the words of Uncle Bob here: blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2017/03/06/TestingLikeTheTSA.h‌​tml Treat 100% [coverage] as an asymptotic goal. – eug.nikolaev

Since java does not allow it, we cannot cover it 100%. 100% junit coverage for branch and line is an idealistic aim, which should be tried for whenever possible. But sometimes, when its not possible, its not possible. Accept it and move on to solve better problems.

Answer (score 0):

We will need to cover all test possibilities for if. In this case, we may have four possibilities.

For example the class:

```
package com.java.basics;

public class Response {

    private String responseBlock;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Response response = new Response();
        if (response != null && response.getResponseBlock() != null) {
            // something
        }
    }

    public String getResponseBlock() {
        return responseBlock;
    }

    public void setResponseBlock(String responseBlock) {
        this.responseBlock = responseBlock;
    }

}
```

Can be tested...

```
package com.java.basics.test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNull;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ResponseTest {

    private Response response;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        response = new Response();
        response.setResponseBlock("Test");
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsResponseIsNull() {
        //25 %
        response = null;
        assertNull(response);
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsResponseIsNotNull() {
        //25 %
        assertNotNull(response);
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsResponseBlockIsNull() {
        //25 %
        response.setResponseBlock(null);
        assertNull(response.getResponseBlock());
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsResponseBlockIsNotNull() {
        //25 %
        assertNotNull(response.getResponseBlock());
    }

}
```